# How to save data from RecyclerView EditText

Tags: java, android, database, android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle

I have RecyclerView with multiple EditText. I want to save data that user provided to the EditText, store it and retrieve it after opening an app again.

I have an app where user tracks how many repetitions of certain exercise they did and obviously I want it to be saved somehow and to be retrieved later, but I don't know how to do this with RecyclerView. Usually I would just send certain EditText data to the database and then I would retrieve it, but in RecyclerView I don't know how to access that data as it is created dynamically(?) Sorry if I am wrong with something, but I am very new in Android programming.

Below is my code.

```
public class exercises extends AppCompatActivity {

    String data1;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    String[] s1,s2,s3;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.squat,R.drawable.pull_up,R.drawable.handstand,R.drawable.leg_raises,
            R.drawable.push_up,R.drawable.dips,R.drawable.horizontal_pull,R.drawable.plank};
    ImageView goBackArrow;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercises);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        goBackArrow = findViewById(R.id.go_back_arrow2);
        data1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("data1");

        Log.d("IntentToExercises", "onCreate: " + data1);


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.exercisesRecyclerView);

        if(data1.equals("SQUATS")) {
            s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEVEL);
            s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SQUATS);
            s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.SQUATS_VIDEOURL);
            ExercisesRecyclerView exercisesRecyclerView = new ExercisesRecyclerView(this,
                    s1,s2,s3);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(exercisesRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        } else if(data1.equals("PULL UPS")){
            s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEVEL);
            s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PULL_UPS);
            s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PULL_UPS_VIDEOURL);
            ExercisesRecyclerView exercisesRecyclerView = new ExercisesRecyclerView(this,
                    s1,s2,s3);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(exercisesRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }else if(data1.equals("HANDSTAND PUSH UPS")){
            s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEVEL);
            s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HANDSTAND);
            s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HANDSTAND_VIDEOURL);
            ExercisesRecyclerView exercisesRecyclerView = new ExercisesRecyclerView(this,
                    s1,s2,s3);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(exercisesRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }else if(data1.equals("LEG RAISES")){
            s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEVEL);
            s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEGRAISES);
            s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEGRAISES_VIDEOURL);
            ExercisesRecyclerView exercisesRecyclerView = new ExercisesRecyclerView(this,
                    s1,s2,s3);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(exercisesRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }else if(data1.equals("PUSH UPS")){
            s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEVEL);
            s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PUSH_UPS);
            s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PUSH_UPS_VIDEOURL);
            ExercisesRecyclerView exercisesRecyclerView = new ExercisesRecyclerView(this,
                    s1,s2,s3);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(exercisesRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }else if(data1.equals("DIPS")){
            s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEVEL);
            s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DIPS);
            s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.DIPS_VIDEOURL);
            ExercisesRecyclerView exercisesRecyclerView = new ExercisesRecyclerView(this,
                    s1,s2,s3);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(exercisesRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }else if(data1.equals("HORIZONTAL PULLS")){
            s1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.LEVEL);
            s2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HORIZONTAL_PULLS);
            s3 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.HORIZONTAL_PULLS_VIDEOURL);
            ExercisesRecyclerView exercisesRecyclerView = new ExercisesRecyclerView(this,
                    s1,s2,s3);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(exercisesRecyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        }
```

Adapter code:

```
public class ExercisesRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExercisesRecyclerView.MyViewHolder>
{
    String[] data1, data2, videoURL;
    int[] images;
    Context context;

        public ExercisesRecyclerView(Context ct, String[] s1, String[] s2, String[] videoArray) {
            context = ct;
            data1 = s1;
            data2 = s2;
            videoURL = videoArray;
        }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercises_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.level.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.description.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.playVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
                AlertDialog dialog;
                dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,null);
                youTubePlayerView = view2.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);


                youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                        String videoID = videoURL[position];
                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID,0);
                        super.onReady(youTubePlayer);
                    }

                });

                dialogBuilder.setView(view2);
                dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data2.length;
    }




    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView level, description;
            ImageView playVideoButton;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            level = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercisesLevelTextView);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercisesNameTextView);
            playVideoButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playVideoButton);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so hard to save data with [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). But, it does take a few lines of code. So, I'd prefer you to use [my library](https://github.com/sambhav2358/TinyDB). It is even faster to use. You can add it to your app using the `README.md` file. Now, I can give you the entire adapter code with that functionality below:

```java
public class ExercisesRecyclerView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExercisesRecyclerView.MyViewHolder>
{
    String[] data1, data2, videoURL;
    int[] images;
    Context context;
    TinyDBManager tinyDB; // added this line

        public ExercisesRecyclerView(Context ct, String[] s1, String[] s2, String[] videoArray) {
            context = ct;
            data1 = s1;
            data2 = s2;
            videoURL = videoArray;
            tinyDB = TinyDB.getInstance(context); // added this line
        }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercises_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.level.setText(data1[position]);
        holder.description.setText(data2[position]);
        holder.playVideoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
                AlertDialog dialog;
                dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,null);
                youTubePlayerView = view2.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);


                youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                        String videoID = videoURL[position];
                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoID,0);
                        super.onReady(youTubePlayer);
                    }

                });

                dialogBuilder.setView(view2);
                dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data2.length;
    }




    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView level, description;
            ImageView playVideoButton;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            level = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercisesLevelTextView);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exercisesNameTextView);
            playVideoButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playVideoButton);

        }
    }
}
```

That does the init part for the db. But, because I don't find your edit text anywhere in the adapter, I have not added that part. But, the code for that edit text will be like this:

```java
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        tinyDB.putString("value", s.toString());
    }
});
```

But, dont forget to change the key in that place according your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your library is really awesome, very easy to use even for a begginer like me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store and retrieve data, you can use Shared Preferences, Data Store or Room Database. With EditText, you need to add TextWatcher for collect text change and save it.